# Composer - Move all files and folder from a folder to the root of the project with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I had a request from a senior, to **move all the Magento content that has been downloaded to the root folder using composer**. He wants to automate the process by just running composer install.

Below is the code I wrote to perform the above task:

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "magento",
            "type": "webroot",
            "version": "1.8",
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://github.com/amacgregor/magento-1.8/archive/master.zip"
            },
            "require" : {
                "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "magento": "1.8",
    "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
},
"extra": {
    "webroot-dir": "public",
    "webroot-package": "magento"
},
"scripts": {
  "post-install-cmd": [
    "php -r \"shell_exec('cp -rf public/. .');\"",
    "php -r \"shell_exec('rm -rf public');\""
  ]
 }
}
```

As you can see I downloaded the package to a public folder and then using the composer script I move them out. **Is the process correct? Will, it in any way hamper the project in the future if I follow this procedure?**

Comment: You are using Composer shell command to start PHP to excecute shell commands... now that's close to the four levels in the movie "Inception". And you avoid using the `mv` command because it is better to physically copy then delete the files, using twice the storage space instead of changing directory pointers faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But Didn't really understand whats the outcome from your comment. Do you have a better way to do the same?

Comment: I criticize you using "php shell_exec(STUFF)" instead of directly calling "STUFF", and for not using the `mv` command to move files.

Comment: I am new to composer. I had no idea that it's possible like thta. I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks for the constructive criticism. Also there is a reason i didnt use the mv file. I was unable to move the hidden files with mv command.